# Postgres ltree: Get all accessable resources by groups and sub groups

Tags: postgresql, hierarchy

Have following Data scheme:

**Roles:**
Each role has either a resource assigned or a resource_group. A user wich has a role on a group has also access to all resources that are within the group or within all child groups

| role_id | resource_id | resource_group_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | null | 1 |

**Resource_Group**
Each resource group may have a parent resource. Additionally store within ltree path

| id | parent_id | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1.2.3 |

**relation_group_resource**
n_m relation to resource table

| resource_group_id | resource_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |

With a query I can get in example all child groups of 1:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE manager_path ~ '*.1.*{1,}';
```

So my target is to get all resource_id's that can be accessed by a user. User 1 could access all resources since the group 1 includes all sup groups which include all resources.

In the best way I would like to create a view to avoid doing joins within the query since views also fast. Also a way to join the ltree column would be a solution.

**What is the best way to get a list of all resources accessible by a role?**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please provide an an example of your tables, data and desired result on dbfiddle.uk - it has the ltree extension enabled! Then copy and paste the text back here. Please do not upload images for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).